# Can a Facebook test offer be created from a test page with 50+ likes from test users?

Tags: facebook, facebook-page, facebook-test-users

I'm trying to test Facebook offers. I figured if I create a test page (test user of my app creates a page).Then I use other test users of my app to get 50+ likes. I figured I should be able to create a test offer. My test page type is "Bank/Financial Services".

The test page has 53 likes now, but I still cannot create an offer.

Do I just need to give it time or is this even possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Facebook got back to me and told me this is not possible under their current design.